# How to hardware decode a Stream from an RTSP source

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtsp, decoder, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have setup an RTSP stream using ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -loglevel warning -re -stream_loop -1 -i path/to/file.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 600k -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -profile:v baseline -an -filter:v scale=1280:-1 -f rtsp rtsp://<IP>:8554/test`

Then I tried to access that stream with the following gstreamer pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://<IP>:8554/test drop-on-latency=true ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! queue ! nvv4l2decoder ! queue ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw, format=(string)RGBA' ! fakesink`

I used a fakesink just to see if the pipeline worked and if the NVDEC was enabled (I am using a Jetson Orin Nano to run this pipeline). However, when running this pipeline I get the following error:

```
libEGL warning: DRI3: failed to query the version
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.12.13:8554/flare
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261 
Stream format not found, dropping the frame
Stream format not found, dropping the frame
```

As you can see I get several messages of the type `Stream format not found, dropping the frame`

In order to debug I changed the RTSP source, and created an RTSP server using: (compiled the [test-launch-c](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/1.16/examples/test-launch.c):

`./test-launch "filesrc location=video.m4v ! qtdemux ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 "`
The `video.m4v` was H264 encoded.

Now, running the previous pipeline with the new RTSP source I have no error.

Why does it happen and how can I change my failing gstreamer pipeline to account for different source formats?

#### **Tests Updated**

As advised by `SeB` I run the previous pipeline in debug mode for both situations, here are my findings:

**FFMPEG Stream** (The problematic one)

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/nvv4l2decoder:nvv4l2decoder0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)30/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)constrained-baseline, level=(string)3.1
```

**RTSP Stream** (Working fine)

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/nvv4l2decoder:nvv4l2decoder0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)596, height=(int)336, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, chroma-format=(string)4:2:0, bit-depth-luma=(uint)8, bit-depth-chroma=(uint)8, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)high, level=(string)3
```

I saw that the profile and level in the working pipeline are "high" and "3" respectively, so I tried to change my previous pipeline to:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.18.10:8554/test drop-on-latency=true ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,profile=high,level=3 ! queue ! nvv4l2decoder enable-max-performance=1 ! queue ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw, format=(string)RGBA' ! fakesink`

Although I do not see the error anymore:

```
libEGL warning: DRI3: failed to query the version
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://192.168.18.10:8554/test
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261
```

The decoder is not being used.

Do I need to add more caps or change where they are applied?

Comment: You may try to use gst-launch -v verbose flag and look at what H264 profile and level are received by decoder in the working and non working cases. nvv4l2decoder may not support all cases depending on resolution, framerate and encoded bitrate.

Comment: Just updated the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may adjust your ffmpeg command to use H264 high profile with level 3.1:

```
... -profile:v high -level:v 3.1 ...
```

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding

Switching to gstreamer RTSP server may also be a better option, especially if later moving to a higher grade Orin module, this may leverage HW NVENC.